# Что означает "::" в с++?

Tags: visual-c++, c

Не смог быстро нагуглить, что означает ::  в с или с++? Гугл не хочет искать по этим символам.
Знаю, что вопрос глупый, но все же.

Comment: Вот [похожий вопрос][1]. 


  [1]: http://hashcode.ru/questions/162284/c-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D1%82

Answer (score 5, accepted):

А вы книгу читали по С++ хоть какую-нибудь? Это ж есть везде.

Вот [отсюда](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/identifiers), например (перевёл):

> *Уточнённый идентификатор* — это идентификатор, имя функции-оператора, имя оператора-литерала или идентификатор шаблона, которому предшествует оператор разрешения области видимости `::`, и, возможно, последовательность имён классов и пространств имён (namespace), разделённых такими же операторами разрешения области видимости.
>
> Например, выражение `std::string::npos` является `id`-выражением, которое именует статический член `npos` класса `string` из пространства имён `std`. Выражение `::tolower` именует функцию `tolower` из глобального пространства имён. Выражение `::std::cout` именует глобальную переменную `cout` из пространства имён *верхнего уровня* `std`. Уточнённый идентификатор `boost::signals2::connection` именует тип `connection`, принадлежащий пространству имён `signals2`, которое само находится в пространстве имён `boost`.

Своими словами: в каждый момент времени у вас есть область видимости имён. Вы можете импортировать в неё (при помощи `using`) другие имена. Когда вы указываете имя, она ищется в вашей области видимости. Но если вы указываете `::`, это модифицирует область видимости. `X::Y` — это то же, что просто `Y`, но ищется в пространстве имён, которое из вашей точки видно как `X`. `::X::Y` — это то же самое, но `X` ищется не в вашей области видимости, а в глобальной (а в этом `X` уже ищется `Y`). И так далее.

Comment: Читал, когда-то давно давно. Придется перечитывать, просто хотелось бы разобраться в коде без долгих перечитываний книг :)

Comment: для этого есть гугол....

Comment: @VladD,а почему :: есть и в WinAPI , он ведь для языка Си создан , а в Си никаких :: нет

Comment: @Elvin: А в каком смысле «есть в WinAPI»? В header'ах WinAPI я такого не видел.

Comment: @VladD,в  этом https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/907441/258486 вопросе мне ответили, и я увидел,что там есть ::

Comment: @Elvin: Ну там код на C++. На C этот же код не скомпилируется. Но в заголовках WinAPI никаких пространств имён нет.

Answer (score 0):

Почитайте об области видимости функций и переменных
http://programmersclub.ru/12/